# How can i register third-party directive with another name?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am upgrading my app from ui-bootstrap 0.11 to to 1.1.2.
As a part of the upgrade i should prefix the directives with "ui"
for example, tab should become ui-tab.
I want to avoid this huge replacement in my code so i thought to register ui-bootstrap directives with their old names (i don't want to touch ui-bootstrap code).
How it can be done? Is there a better way?